# ios URL Scheme for Google Home App

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, url-scheme, google-home

Request to help with URL Scheme for Google Home Application. 

 I would like to open Google Home App from my existing app through URL Scheme. Unable to get URL Scheme for Google Home. 

We have URL Scheme available for Maps, Music and all. Unable to get the Home App.

Comment: **The Google Cast app is now called 'Google Home'**

Comment: I'm looking for URL Scheme to open the google home app from my iphone app. Yes i know its been changed to Google Home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deeplink that you are searching is:

`chromecast://`

you may try it in your browser, it will open Google Home

Comment: Ravi - if this is the answer, then please mark it as such!